# Join another window in Qt Designer, using Python

Tags: python, qt, visible

I am using:

- Python
- PyQT
- Qt Designer

I want that if a button for example is clicked, that a new window appears. There you can click something, press ok and the information is given to the mainwindow.

I don't know how to realize that.

And the second little problem is: I want to make some things visible if a button is clicked. I imagine the things in the following way.

I set the default-value of the attribute "visible" to false. Click the button and switch it to true. But I didn't found an attribute which is called visible or sth like this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a class. What I've done before is store all the variables in the class then use a QStacked layout to hold every window that will be shown then when the button is clicked just change it to that screen. There is probably a better way to do it than this, I'm just familiar with this way.

I used this tutorial [Python School](http://www.pythonschool.net/switchinglayouts/). If your new to PyQt it might be worth viewing the whole GUI series.
Hope this helps

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this site until now. Looks great. Thanks!

Comment: My teach told me about when I was just starting now I cant use it any more! They have ran out of things for me to do. They are really helpful on their they are happy for you to email if you are really stuck. Most of them teach comp science at uni's